# Group data by date and id and get the last record of current group and first record of previous group in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    the_debt_pay_id varchar(8) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_due date NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0105', '2020-08-02', '2020-08-02 11:22:04'), 
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0104', '2020-07-02', '2020-05-18 11:07:01'), 
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0103', '2020-06-02', '2020-05-18 11:17:20'), 
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0102', '2020-05-02', '2020-04-01 02:28:41'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0101', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-01 06:29:53'),
       ('LMUS01', 'LMUS0100', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-01 06:59:32'),
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0202', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-02 07:30:59'),   
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0201', '2020-02-02', '2020-01-31 06:58:18'),
       ('LMUS02', 'LMUS0200', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03 09:34:20')
```

Given a determined `the_debt_pay_id` I want the last `the_debt_due` from the group of `the_debt_id` and `the_debt_paid` (as a date), and the first `the_debt_due` of the previous group.

As a guide, I will partition by `the_debt_id`, I will sort the table by `the_debt_due` and explain the groups:

```
the_debt_id   the_debt_pay_id   the_debt_due   grouped the_debt_id & the_debt_paid date
LMUS01        LMUS0100          2020-03-02     LMUS01&2020-03-01 (group 1)
LMUS01        LMUS0101          2020-04-02     LMUS01&2020-04-01 (group 2)    
LMUS01        LMUS0102          2020-05-02     LMUS01&2020-04-01 (group 2)
LMUS01        LMUS0103          2020-06-02     LMUS01&2020-05-18 (group 3) 
LMUS01        LMUS0104          2020-07-02     LMUS01&2020-05-18 (group 3)
LMUS01        LMUS0105          2020-08-02     LMUS01&2020-08-02 (group 4)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
LMUS02        LMUS0200          2020-01-02     LMUS02&2020-01-03 (group 1)
LMUS02        LMUS0201          2020-02-02     LMUS02&2020-01-31 (group 2)
LMUS02        LMUS0202          2020-03-02     LMUS02&2020-03-02 (group 3)
```

Let's say that I want as pointers LMUS0103 and LMUS0202. For the `the_debt_pay_id` LMUS0103, it belongs to "group 3", so I want the last `the_debt_due` which is 2020-07-02. The previous group is "group 2" and its first `the_debt_due` is 2020-04-02.

For the `the_debt_pay_id` LMUS0202, it is in the "group 3", so the last is the only 2020-03-02. The previous group ("group 2") has only one record, so the first `the_debt_due` is 2020-02-02.

This is the expected output

```
the_debt_id     the_debt_pay_id    the_debt_due_lt      the_debt_due_previous_ft
LMUS01          LMUS0103           2020-07-02           2020-04-02
LMUS02          LMUS0202           2020-03-02           2020-02-02
```

I tried this, but I'm stuck:

```
SELECT *(SELECT the_debt_id, the_debt_pay_id, 
LAST_VALUE(the_debt_due) OVER(PARTITION BY the_debt_id, the_debt_paid::DATE ORDER BY the_debt_due) the_debt_due_lt) 
FIRST_VALUE(LAG(the_debt_due)) OVER(PARTITION BY the_debt_id, the_debt_paid::DATE) the_debt_due_ft
FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_pay_id IN ('LMUS0103','LMUS0202')
```

Comment: Please recheck your output? it is inconsistent

Comment: How you expect the `2020-02-02` as last debt due`'LMUS0202'`?

Comment: @Manu . . . Your description does not make any sense to me.  Can you be clearer?  For instance, why don't you have all `the_debt_pay_id` in the results?  And what is "the previous group"?

Comment: Sure @Gordon Linoff, let me explain my question, I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your query as per updated question:

```
with cte as (select distinct 
the_debt_id,
dense_rank() over (partition by the_debt_id order by date(the_debt_paid)) "rank_",
min(the_debt_due) over (partition by the_debt_id,date(the_debt_paid) order by date(the_debt_paid)) "min_date"
from my_table
),

cte1 as (
select 
*,
max(the_debt_due) over (partition by the_debt_id order by date(the_debt_paid)) "max_date",
dense_rank() over (partition by the_debt_id order by date(the_debt_paid)) "rank_"
from my_table
)

select 
t1.the_debt_id,
t1.the_debt_pay_id,
t1.max_date,
t2.min_date
from cte1 t1 
left join cte t2 on t2.the_debt_id=t1.the_debt_id and t2.rank_=t1.rank_-1
where t1.the_debt_pay_id IN ('LMUS0103','LMUS0202')
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7794d0c4fc94cffac71167fe50d84cb7)

Comment: Hello @Akhilesh Mishra, as per your comment I edited my question to better explain how the expected output is obtained.

Comment: Hello @Akhilesh Mishra, thank you for your time, I tested the condition of the "previous group" but it doesn't tested well in your query.

Comment: @Manu can you explain the problem with some more data.

Comment: Sure @Akhilesh Mishra, I added more rows to the dataset to better explain the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Akhilesh Mishra, in the expected output for LMUS01 the min should be `2020-04-02` because is the group before "group 3".

Comment: @Manu I have updated the answer again with above clarification

Comment: Hello @Akhilesh Mishra, thank you very much. I have added more rows in the fiddle to test your answer and works great, using CTEs, grouping with dense rank was a smart move. My apologies that my question was confusing. Have a great day.